# Asp.net MVC Handling Model Status

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database-design

IE: A model called Equipment responsible for storing information about equipments, and its status.

My question is, what is the efficient way to store an item's status. My approach is creating different model called EquipmentStatus. But when it comes to write the code, you need to write code like below :

```
if(equiment.equipmentstatusid == 2)
```

I think it is not good approach. What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: I don't really follow.  What's wrong with having your `Equipment` Model contain an `EquipmentStatus` model?

Comment: You probably want to be using an Enum.

Comment: What does EquipmentStatus store?

Comment: @Jonesy If i use EquipmentStatus table, i need to handle status depends on ID. Ie. 5-Closed 6-Opened status in one of my customer. But for other customer it can be changed, so i need to change all of the codes.

Comment: @Nilesh EquipmentStatus stores only ID and StatusName

Comment: Enum can be usefull. @Calum

Comment: Yep, then as @Calum said Enum would be always useful. You can write a DB driven enum and then use `Switch Case` based on the enum value.

Comment: You can use `Enum.Parse` as `int i = 2;
            var val =  (Status) Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), i.ToString());` And then use `Switch(val)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code but if you want to do it in efficient way, use can [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Also see this great post. [When to use Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119714/when-to-use-enums-and-when-to-replace-them-with-a-class-with-static-members)

```
public enum Status
{
    Success = 1,
    Failed = 2,
    Default = 3
}

if(equiment.equipmentstatusid == (int)Status.Success)
{
 //something
}
```