# Get all types under each category using enum in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have 2 enums

```
 enum Categories{
        Entertainment=100,
        Food=200,
        Medical=300
        };


 enum Types
        {
            Multiplex = 101,
            GameZone,
            Bar = 201,
            Hotel,
            Cafe,
            Hospital = 301,
            Clinic 
        };
```

I want to list out all types under particular category
eg.
If i give Entertainment as input output list will contain Multiplex and Gamezone

How should I do this?

Comment: Why are you using enums for relational data?

Comment: That looks like a really horrible way to relate that data.

Comment: How it relates with each other? Please look at [When to use enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119714/when-to-use-enums-and-when-to-replace-them-with-a-class-with-static-members)

Comment: Can we use structure for it

Comment: Do you need to relate behavior to the different types or categories? ie. all Entertainment types specify the number of people that can be served, or all cafes will have a menu, or things like that, or is this more like just a category + subcategory (types in your question), and you just need to "tag" some other piece of data?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I just need relationship between Categories & Types. I have 16 categories & 96 types.

Comment: I would go with something like what @Christos suggests in his answer over this implicit relationship personally. At the very least, make a helper method somewhere and use this everywhere you need to from a category to a set of types, so that you don't spread this bad design all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use a dictionary for you purpose, like below:

```
Dictionary<Categories,List<Types>> dictionary = new Dictionary<Categories, List<Types>>()
{
    { Categories.Entertainment, new List<Types> { Types.Multiplex , Types.GameZone} },
    { Categories.Food, new List<Type> { Types.Bar, Types.Hotel, Types.Cafe }}
};
```

This way you could retrive the corresponding list, giving the right key, like below:

```
dictionary[Categories.Entertainment]
```

would return the list with elements

`Types.Multiplex` and `Types.GameZone`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this looks like a really bad design. You have implicit relationships, and not explicit ones (ie. a dictionary or similar type of explicitly denoting what goes with what).

I would seriously consider finding a different way to organise these things.

However, be that as it may, here's one way to obtain the types:

```
var cat = Categories.Entertainment;

var types =
    from Types type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Types))
    where (int)type >= (int)cat && (int)type < (int)cat+100
    select type;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest decorating the type enum values with a custom attribute that pointed it back to the category.

I understand that you have put in range values but my preference would be custom attributes.

Example

With the attribute

```
public class CategoryAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private readonly Category _category;

        public Category Category
        {
            get
            {
                return _category;
            }
        }

        public CategoryAttribute(Category category)
        {
            _category = category;
        }
    }
```

You could have some methods similar to

```
public static Category GetCateogryFromType(Types categoryType)
        {
            var memberInfo = typeof(Types).GetMember(categoryType.ToString())
                                                      .FirstOrDefault();

            if (memberInfo != null)
            {
                var attribute = (CategoryAttribute)memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CategoryAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    return attribute.Category;
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("No category found");
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Types> GetCategoryTypes(Category category)
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Types)).Cast<Types>();
            return values.Where(t => GetCateogryFromType(t) == category);
        }
```

And then decorate your types like this

```
public enum Types
    {
        [Category(Category.Entertainment)]
        Multiplex,
        [Category(Category.Entertainment)]
        GameZone,
        [Category(Category.Food)]
        Bar,
        [Category(Category.Food)]
        Hotel,
        [Category(Category.Food)]
        Cafe,
        [Category(Category.Medical)]
        Hospital,
        [Category(Category.Medical)]
        Clinic
    }
```

Then you could call

```
GetCategoryTypes(Category.Entertainment).ToList();
```

Oh and I renamed your Categories enum to Category :-p