# Generic input parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to implement a generic function, Let's say we have Modes & it's corresponding Sub modes
[image]

Now what I have done was I've created an Enum for Modes

```
public enum Modes
{
    ModeA,
    ModeB,
    ModeC
}
```

and similarly for SubModes,

```
public enum SubModesA
{
    SubModeA1,
    SubModeA2,
    SubModeA3
}

public enum SubModesB
{
    SubModeB1,
    SubModeB2
}

public enum SubModesC
{
    SubModeC1,
    SubModeC2,
    SubModeC3
}
```

Now my question is, How to implement a Method(it could be a generic) which takes in `Mode` as one input, `Sub Modes` as second input, please note that the second input(Sub Modes) has to be based on first input,

(Ex. `Public void PerformOperation(Modes mode, SubModes subMode){};`

any ideas please?

Comment: Do they have to be `enum` types? EDIT: Just to clarify, could they be classes with a fixed set of members (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119714/when-to-use-enums-and-when-to-replace-them-with-a-class-with-static-members), or could they be anything else?

Comment: You would be better served for your PerformOperation method to take an interface as a parameter, and then perform the operation on the interface type.  That way you don't have to add to the enumeration every time you add a new operation.

Comment: Enums would be ideal, as the user could see the corresponding subModes when they type.

Comment: @San': So is this purely about achieving some nice intellisense/API for developers consuming your code? Did you have any other plans (serialization for example?)

Comment: This sounds like polymorphic behavior, you should use *actual polymorphism* instead of forcing some enum switch.

Comment: @Chris, Yeah I agree at the same time, I want to make sure it's just one method, the other option would be to use multiple functions with different input parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to get this behavior using an `enum` for your mode.  You'll need to use a mechanism that involves having a different type for each mode, so that each mode can map to a different overload of a method.  You can use a class like this to accomplish that:

```
public class Mode
{
    public static readonly ModeA ModeA = new ModeA();
    public static readonly ModeB ModeA = new ModeB();
    public static readonly ModeC ModeA = new ModeC();
    public class ModeA { }
    public class ModeB { }
    public class ModeC { }
}
```

Now you can write methods such as this:

```
public static void PerformOperation(Mode.ModeA mode, SubModesA subMode)
{

}
```

You can create methods for each type of mode, each having the appropriate sub mode.  This means that a caller can now write:

```
PerformOperation(Mode.ModeA,
```

and the only valid values for the second parameter are instances of the appropriate submode.

Comment: Thanks Servy, Interesting one but Not sure if I understand this one though.

Comment: @San' What don't you understand?

Comment: It's clear now, the thing that I didn't understand was `SubModesA` parameter in `PerformOperation()` method, later I realized it's the Enum. This is pretty much similar to having three methods, from which the first input Parameter is same (`Modes`) for all the methods, and the second parameter can be different.

Answer (score 2):

With your current structure, this is not possible. Generic type constraints are pretty limited in what they allow you to constrain. Effectively, you can restrict to classes (`new`) and enforce derivation from a class or interface.

If you made the enums *objects* and the various `SubModesA` derived from `ModeA`, and `ModeA` derive from `Mode` then you could do:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T,U> where T : Mode
                                 where U : T
```

You may want to consider a number of other patterns (template method, strategy come to mind) in order to handle this case.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I will try this approach.