# How do I make an enum or something similar with a structure?

Tags: c#

I want to have an enum and each element of the enum has its own structure?

Example:

```
public enum Rarity : Color
{
    Rare = new Color(255,255,255),
}

Color color = Rarity.Rare
```

I know that you cannot enter anything other than numbers, but how can this be done so that it works, is it possible without enum?

Comment: search for: "enum as a class"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119714/when-to-use-enums-and-when-to-replace-them-with-a-class-with-static-members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't quite the classic "enum which looks like a class case", since you just want a collection of a pre-existing type.

In your case, you probably just want a static class, where each member is an instance of `Color`:

```
public static class Rarity
{
    public static Color Rare => new Color(255, 255, 255);
    // ...
}
```

This is what the built-in [`Colors`](https://source.dot.net/#PresentationCore/System/Windows/Media/Knowncolors.cs,0584e1e7d7fb612c) type does.

Comment: I know. But how then to choose?

With enum I could do Rarity rarity = Rarity.Rare;

How can I do the same with the class?

Comment: I'm confused. If you want to be able to do `Rarity rarity = Rarity.Rate`, then you can just use an enum. Alternatively, do the same as I've done above, but do `public static Rarity Rare ....`